# Windows 10 Upgrade causing Error Connection Time Out

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, http

I can't seem to find an answer to this problem I'm having.

Hardware, Alienware 13 Laptop purchased in the last year.  Upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1.

Issue, most sites but not all, I get connection time outs when browsing.  This happens across all browsers, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge.  Some sites are iffy, sometimes working, sometimes not working.  But it does seem the larger number of hops, the greater chance of failing.

In Chrome, I get the message:  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.  Microsoft browsers give a generic this page can not be displayed error.

I did the upgrade in the first week Windows 10 was available and the problem started right away.  I rolled back to 8.1, and the problem went away.  I decided to give Windows 10 some time and try again.  I ran the upgrade again last night, and same problem again.  I've tried upgrading drivers (network, chipset and wireless) and bios, but so far nothing has seemed to work.

I've tried flushing the dns cache, clearing web cache and connecting to a different access point.  I can ping most sites but http connections are timing out.  Also when printing from windows 10, only the first part of the document gets printed.  On the test print, only the top 2 inches gets printed.  Also turning windows firewall off, seems to help some but I still can't access a lot of sites.

Comment: if you think its for windows you can easily refresh your windows 10 so it will re install itself but make sure you have back up of your files